# npm ERR! Cannot read property 'version' of null

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, npm

I can't install anything in it, tried solutions in here but did not work any either.

```
$ npm install axios
npm ERR! Cannot read property '**version**' of null

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-26T13_54_26_790Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Check the generated log for more details, maybe share some relevant parts from that here as well

Comment: What is installed node version? Are you using nvm?

Answer (score 1):

Try to cleanup node cache and remove node_modules:

```
$ npm cache clean --force
$ rm -rf node_modules
```

After try to run npm install axios.

Comment: Cool, I was having same issue and solve by clearing the npm cache. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

can you please check your
npmlockversion in the package-lock.json ,
and you npm version?

if you are using npmlockversion 3 you should use npm version higher than 7.

Comment: I was facing this error - "cannot read property axios of undefined" after running the command "npm ci" in docker container. The issue was - I was using lock file version as "3" and npm version as "6.14". Downgrading lock file version solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this error generally came when you used any deprecated library on your project. so just go through your package.json file and remove those deprecated library which you have been used...

simply remove that versions from package.json and do

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

if it will not resolved then try run this

```
npm install axios --legacy-peer-deps
```